# Defaults with nested object

Tags: javascript, object, default-value

Suppose I have the following object which provides the default value:

```js
default_values = {a: 0, b: 0, c: {aa: 0, bb: 0}}
```

I also have another object that would override some of these default values:

```js
override_values = {a: 5, c: {aa: 5}}
```

What I'd like to have is to combine these two objects that would result in

```js
combined: {a: 5, b: 0, c: {aa: 5, bb: 0}}
```

However, using the regular spread operator like `{...default_values, ...override_values}` would just give `c: {aa: 5}` instead of `c: {aa: 5, bb: 0}`. The object could be huge so I can't hard-code all the nested objects.

I could write a function to basically go over each key... if the value is not an object then use `override | default`, otherwise recursively call this function on the nested object. But I feel like this is very common that there's already something like this.

Comment: just search for javascript deep merge

Comment: You either explicitly spell out nested objects to be merged (`{…, c:{...combined.c, ...override_values.c}}`) or indeed write such a function for generically merging arbitrarily deep objects. There is no builtin for this.

Comment: You can use a deep merge library such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/deepmerge

Comment: lodash has `_.defaultsDeep` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#defaultsDeep

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something along the lines of deep_merge or merge.
These functions are widely and are presented in `lodash` library.

Here is an example of it:-

```
function merge(target, source) {
  Object.keys(source).forEach(key => {
    const sourceValue = source[key];
    if (sourceValue) {
      const targetValue = target[key];
      const newValues = merge(targetValue, sourceValue);
      Object.assign(sourceValue, newValues);
    }
  });

  Object.assign(target || {}, source);
  return target;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a deep merge.

```js
const
    isObject = o => o && typeof o === 'object',
    merge = (a, b) => {
        Object
            .entries(b)
            .forEach(([k, v]) => a[k] = isObject(v) ? merge(a[k] || {}, v) : v);
        return a;
    },
    default_values = { a: 0, b: 0, c: { aa: 0, bb: 0 } },
    override_values = { a: 5, c: { aa: 5 } },
    result = merge(default_values, override_values);

console.log(result);
```